# Rspec giving false result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

Hi I'm writing test case where I have to check if correct parameters are send to the controller or not below is my `rspec`

```
context 'when some button is clicked ' do
it 'some other button value  in the DOM has to set false value' do
  find("label[for='someButton']").click()
  click_button('Save')
  allow_any_instance_of(SomeController).to receive(:update) do |*args|
    expect(args[0].params[:some][:some_param]).to be('xyz') # but here params[:some][:some_param] is 'true' still the test case is passing
   end
  end
 end
```

i'm getting  `params[:some][:some_param] = 'true'` but still test case is passing 
any idea !!!

Comment: You are mixing acceptance with unit tests so you should decide if you want to test how the app behaves in the general or only given portion of code

Comment: I think the expect is never ran in the context of the test actually, when there is no expect ran in a test, it returns true by default, I'm not sure you can use an expect inside the stub of a method. Why not use expect_any_instance_of(SomeController).to receive(:update).with
or something else from rspec-mocks to write this without putting the expect inside the method block